# Regroup all the javascript function in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, document-ready

How to regroup all these `javascript` functions in one,

Instead of to have  a lots of `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

I want to have only one where I will find all my functions.

Here is all functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openNav()  { document.getElementById("myNav").style.cssText = "height:100%"; document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";}
function closeNav() { document.getElementById("myNav").style.cssText = "height:0%";  document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";}
</script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();    
if(scrolltop >= 1150) {
$('#fixedbar').fadeIn(100);
}    
else if(scrolltop <= 1150) {
$('#fixedbar').fadeOut(100);
}
});
});
</script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#voirmoins").on("click", function() {
$(this).toggleClass("on");
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
$(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
});
});
</script>
```

Here is what I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openNav()  { document.getElementById("myNav").style.cssText = "height:100%"; document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";}
function closeNav() { document.getElementById("myNav").style.cssText = "height:0%";  document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";}    

$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();
if(scrolltop >= 1150) {
$('#fixedbar').fadeIn(100);
} 
else if(scrolltop <= 1150) {
$('#fixedbar').fadeOut(100);
}
});
});

$('a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
});

$("#voirmoins").on("click", function() {
$(this).toggleClass("on");
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
$(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: In fact I have a lots of separate <script type="text/javascript"></script> as you can see in my first part of code, but it will be more simple for me if I can have all these functions in one <script type="text/javascript"></script> like my second part of code. So I just want to know if my second part of code is ok, there is no errors ?

Comment: Yes I tried it and all is ok for me, all works fine, but it's ok like that ? I did it right ?

Comment: I suspect your enter key has glued to your keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple tools that will allow you to check the syntax of your JavaScript code. Most commonly known as "lints", googling `javascript lint` will surely help you on your way.

Now to quickly check the syntactical correctness of your code, press F12 in google chrome to open the developer console, paste your js code in here and press enter and it should tell you if there are any syntax errors.

You had two `$(document).ready(...)` statements.

Here, put this between your script brackets:

```
function openNav()  {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.cssText = "height:100%";
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.cssText = "height:0%";
    document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll',function() {
        var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scrolltop >= 1150) {
            $('#fixedbar').fadeIn(100);
        }
        else if(scrolltop <= 1150) {
            $('#fixedbar').fadeOut(100);
        }
    });

    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});

$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});

$("#voirmoins").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

Comment: you are right thank you, you regroup the 2 functions with one $(document).ready(...) thank you, how it works javascript lint, I just need to go to the online lint and past my part of code ?

Comment: No problem, if this worked for you, please mark the answer as correct. As for the JS Lint, basically you paste any javascript code into it and it will tell you if there are any syntax errors and or any suggestions.